# cannot start a react project with yarn start

Tags: reactjs, typescript, yarnpkg

I create react app with create-react-app and when I use yarn start the following error happens:

[image]

Here is the package.json of the project folder:

```
{
  "name": "letmeask",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

and here is the package.json from upath folder:

```
{
  "name": "upath",
  "description": "A proxy to `path`, replacing `\\` with `/` for all results & new methods to normalize & join keeping leading `./` and add, change, default, trim file extensions.",
  "version": "1.2.0",
  "homepage": "http://github.com/anodynos/upath/",
  "author": {
    "name": "Angelos Pikoulas",
    "email": "agelos.pikoulas@gmail.com"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "keywords": [
    "path",
    "unix",
    "windows",
    "extension",
    "file extension",
    "replace extension",
    "change extension",
    "trim extension",
    "add extension",
    "default extension"
  ],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/anodynos/upath"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "http://github.com/anodynos/upath/issues",
    "email": "agelos.pikoulas@gmail.com"
  },
  "main": "./build/code/upath.js",
  "types": "./upath.d.ts",
  "preferGlobal": false,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt",
    "build": "grunt lib"
  },
  "directories": {
    "doc": "./doc",
    "dist": "./build"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=4",
    "yarn": "*"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "~4.0.2",
    "coffee-script": "1.12.6",
    "grunt": "0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-urequire": "0.7.x",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "mocha": "~3.4.2",
    "uberscore": "0.0.19",
    "underscore.string": "^3.3.5",
    "urequire": "0.7.0-beta.33",
    "urequire-ab-specrunner": "^0.2.5",
    "urequire-rc-inject-version": "^0.1.6"
  }
}
```

I've tried yarn install, yarn update, npm install, npm upgrade, vscode reinstall, but nothing works.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You say npm install did not work so far? Then yarn start wouldn't work either consequentially as the required modules are not present. Can you post the log output of npm install please?

Comment: https://imgur.com/tTu7UIF

Comment: The image does not show an error as far as I can see. Please add the entire image or even better the entire log to the question so that everyone can see. From there we might be able to tell the prroblem

Comment: the npm install command don't return any error, but also didn't solve the problem, with or without this command the same error happens

Comment: Then your original question is slightly off. You said you tried 'npm install [...], but nothing works'. Installing is fine and we could now move to the next thought. Try to be as precise as possible when asking questions

Comment: none of the commands works to solve the problem, the modules that can't be find, don't have any conection with the npm package

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting your `yarn.lock` and run `yarn install` again. Also, running `npm install` when you're using yarn isn't recommended. It may cause issues if you mix two package managers in one project.
If you did run `npm install` and ended up creating a `package-lock.json`, please delete that as well and stick to yarn commands for this project in the future.